# UDP server - are asynchronous call worth the extra complexity?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, udp, scalability

I'm writing UDP servers that need to handle a large number of clients.

The protocols are very simple - a single UDP packet arrives and gets decoded. It may require a small acknowledgement packet. The results are usually stored in a database.

Currently I'm using a single threaded UDP server design. It waits for data with a blocking receive call, does some fairly quick processing on the data, then sticks it in a queue so that the slow DB stuff can be done by another process in the background.

I could use the asynchronous UDP calls (BeginReceieve, EndReceive), but I wonder will I gain anything in performance terms?

Lots of people say "if you want scalability you need to use the asynchronous calls". It seems to be received wisdom.  I've used twisted before, so I'm not scared of asynchronous design.

I can see why with TCP, or even with some more complex UDP protocols, async is good. It helps avoid one thread per connection in TCP servers. But my protocol doesn't really require waiting, except when there's nothing to do because no data is arriving.

As I understand it, the async calls will either complete synchronously if no blocking is required, or will start a background thread from the thread pool that will wait for data and call your callback when some is there, or when sending is complete, or when whatever operation you were doing is done.

I think I might "accidentally" gain a little because when a blocking receive is required, the resulting fairly fast decoding will be done in a worker thread rather than the main thread. However, as far as I can tell the receive will only block when there's not much data to process, i.e. when such a minimal gain would be least useful.  Also, the same gain could be achieved without async if it were worth it.

So, my main thread is doing one of 4 things - blocking waiting for data, receiving data, processing data or sending data. I think the only other bit that async might remove from the main thread is time taken to actually receive or send a packet, but I don't know how quickly those complete - if UDP sends are queued by the driver, for example or if the blocking call actually waits till the data is on the wire.

Can anyone tell me if I'd really gain from using asynchronous calls here, and if so, can you explain exactly why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use UDP, your sends never block, and you don't need to multiplex several sockets (or if you do, only a small number).

So a single thread just doing everything would probably be fine.

Personally I'd view using some fancy asynchronous framework as a premature optimisation. Provided your server's scope doesn't change (so that it needs to send on other requests to other servers, for example), it's going to be very easy.

---

As you are saving stuff into a database however, the database could be arbitrarily slow (even a single row insert can take a long time if the DB is busy). You should definitely not do the database inserts synchronously with the network, unless you have some durability guarantees to make.

Does it matter if a few database inserts get lost? You could queue them in memory (if the server goes down, then they are lost). You could queue them on disc and synch the file (but that potentially requires a decent IO controller) then send the response synchronously.

Asychronous database APIs don't normally exist (I have no idea whether you have one), so if your thread gets blocked on a DB write, it blocks the whole task. However, if you have a durability guarantee to meet, then you can't really do much else.

If your spec says that "when the receiver receives a confirmation the data will definitely be stored durably" then you must do the database action synchronously.

Comment: Hi Mark. I said above it "sticks [the data] in a queue so that the slow DB stuff can be done by another process in the background."  I use a concurrent queue and a separate thread to do the database stuff, meaning everything that's done synchronously is fast.  I'm trying to work out the best strategy for making the queue persistent if the process terminates, but that's another issue :)  Also, the acks are receive acks, not anything more.
That said, I'm not talking about a very fancy async framework.  Just the standard .Net BeginReceive/EndReceive/AsyncCallback/IAsyncResult arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about numbers. You said that network thread do some little preprocessing and then delegated message processing to a background thread where all DB stuff take a place. This model should be enough in most cases if you use UDP, since this protocol does not imply a lot of blocking when sending messages.

But again, it's all about numbers. How much percent of CPU time you spent on message preprocessing (0.5% or 15%)? How much time you need to send UDP packet? The OS will block you until underlying buffer have enough space for you message to sent. In most cases it's not the problem, but you may have some specific circumstances.

I recommends you to do some simple load testing to gather numbers and make a decision. AFAIU all you need to know is throughput of message processing. If throughput capacity is enough to process your message stream, there is no need to worry.